# Python if-statement does not loop through the elif and else statement parts

Tags: python, xml, if-statement, variables, printing

I'm trying to open an XML file and parse through it, looking through its tags and finding the text within each specific tag. If the text within the tag matches a string, I want it remove a part of the string or substitute it with something else.

However, it looks like for some reason the code stays inside the third if-statement and thinks that end_int always equals none. I'm not sure why because when finding the value of the variable end_int, I had printed out the values and it gets all the 'end_char' tag values from the xml file, which is what end_int should be. But inside the if statement, it thinks end_char is always None.

The mfn_pn variable is a barcode inputted by the user, something similar to ATL-157-1815, DFW-184-8378., ATL-324-3243., DFW-432-2343, ATL 343 8924, DFW 342 3413, DFW-324 3423 T&R.

The XML file has the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <filter>
        <regex>ATL|LAX|DFW</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>DFW.+\.$</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char>-1</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\-</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\s</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>1P</regex >
        <start_char>2</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>T&#038;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
</metadata>
```

The Python code I'm using is:

```
import re
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

# filters.xml is the file that holds the things to be filtered
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("filters.xml")

# Get the data in the XML file 
root = tree.getroot()

# Loop through filters
for x in root.findall('filter'):

    # Find the text inside the regex tag
    regex = x.find('regex').text
    # Find the text inside the start_char tag
    start_prim = x.find('start_char')
    
    # If the element exists assign its text to start variable
    start = start_prim.text if start_prim is not None else None
    start_int = int(start) if start is not None else None
    print('start: ', start_int)

    # Find the text inside the end_char tag
    end_prim = x.find('end_char')

    # If the element exists assign its text to end variable
    end = end_prim.text if end_prim is not None else None
    end_int = int(end) if end is not None else None
    print('end: ', end_int)

    # Find the text inside the action tag
    action = x.find('action').text

    if action == 'remove':
        if re.match(r'%s' % regex, mfn_pn, re.IGNORECASE):
            print('if statement start:', start_int)
            print('if statement end:', end_int)
            if end_int == None:
                print('if statement start_int:', start_int)
                print('if statement end_int:', end_int)
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:]
            elif start_int == None:
                print('elif statement start_int:' ,start_int)
                print('elif statement end_int:', end_int)
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[:end_int]
            else: 
                print('else statement start_int:', start_int)
                print('else statement end_int:', end_int)
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:end_int]
    elif action == 'substitute':
        mfn_pn = re.sub(r'%s' % regex, '', mfn_pn)
```

For the print statements inside the elif and else statements, nothing prints out because for some reason, the code thinks start_int never equals "None" and all the other cases for the else statement don't work either. It thinks that end_int == 'None' is always true and I'm not sure why it would think that because printing out "end_int" outside the if-statements get all the end_char values from the XML file.

Comment: If nothing is printing, then it must be that the `re.match()` call is returning false.

Comment: @John Gordon It prints in the inside the if statement, but not in the elif or else. Which means it thinks the case in the if statement is always true, but I'm not sure why because outside of the if statements, when I print out the variable when it is first found, it prints out correctly - just not inside the if statement.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the output, so we can see what you mean?

Comment: I just stepped through the code all for `'filter'` tags from your example with `mfn_pn = 'ATL-157-1815'` and it looked like it did everything it was told to.

Comment: @wwii If you try 'DFW-324 3423 T&R' or 'DFW-184-8378.' does it work for you? I tried some more debugging and it looks like re.match() is not finding a match to delete "DFW.+\.$" (DFW at the beginning and '.' at the end, or to delete " T&amp;R$" at the end of the string. I'm not sure if maybe I have the syntax wrong for the regex?

Comment: Using 'DFW-324 3423 T&R' ; the first filter removes the first three characters making `mfn_pn='-324 3423 T&R'` ; the regex for the second filter does not match because the pattern requires the string to start with `'DFW'` but it does not.

Comment: Are you sure `&amp;` is being translated to `&`?

Comment: I've updated the &amp; with &#038;  - this seems to be the correct way to use ampersand in xml, however, re.match still isn't finding " T&#038;R$".

Comment: <continued> ;  the third filter removes the *dash* making mfn_pn=`'324 3423 T&R'`; the fourth filter removes all the spaces making mfn_pn=`'3243423T&R'` ; the fifth filter fails to remove T&R because the regex pattern is `' T&R$'` notice the space in the pattern.

Comment: I took the space out of ' T&R$' and replaced the ampersand so now it's 'T&#038;R$' but re.match is still not finding that as a match at the end. I'm not sure why. Also, the same thing for the "1P" filter. If the mfn_pn is '1PATL-157-2323', it doesn't filter out the '1P'. Not sure if I have the syntax wrong for the regex.

Comment: Seems like you need to be asking questions about specific regex pattern matching problems you are having. Or play around in something like regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

> try 'DFW-324 3423 T&R'

```
mfn_pn = 'DFW-324 3423 T&R'
```

- the first filter removes the first three characters

  - ```
    mfn_pn = '-324 3423 T&R'
    ```
- the second filter regex does not match because the pattern requires the string to start with 'DFW'.

  - ```
    mfn_pn = '-324 3423 T&R'
    ```
- the third filter removes the dash

  - ```
    mfn_pn = '324 3423 T&R'
    ```
- the fourth filter removes all the spaces

  - ```
    mfn_pn='3243423T&R'
    ```
- the fifth filter fails to remove `T&R` because the regex pattern is `' T&R$'` notice the space in the pattern.

  - ```
    mfn_pn='3243423T&R'
    ```

Your xml data for the fourth filter is wrong - change it to

```
...
    <filter>
        <regex>.*T&amp;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
```

or change it to

```
...
    <filter>
        <regex>T&amp;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
```

---

If you want the second filter to remove a single period at the end change it to

```
...
    <filter>
        <regex>[.]$</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char>-1</end_char>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
```

---

Be careful every filter tag iteration may mutate the string so the order of removal and substitution is important.

Comment: For some reason, doing "T&amp;R$" didn't work for me. "*T&amp;R$" did work, however. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Sophia In my answer I gave two alternatives for that filter, a *substitute* with pattern of `.*T&amp;R$` and a *remove* with a pattern of `T&amp;R$` - both of them work.